# ValueError: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False. You should leave random_state to its default (None)

Tags: python, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection, pycaret

Whilst working on an anomaly detection problem on PyCaret, I ran into this issue. I couldn't find that many resources online, unfortunately:

```
from pycaret.datasets import get_data
dataset = get_data("mice")
data_train = dataset.sample(frac=0.95, random_state=786)
data_train.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

from pycaret.anomaly import *
anomaly1 = setup(data=data_train, normalize=True,
             ignore_features=["MouseID"],
             session_id=123)
```

Here is my error:

```
ValueError: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False. You should leave random_state to its default (None), or set shuffle=True.
```